# How to access Styx Browser & Duckduckgo sessions/tabs on my Android & transferring them to my Linux PC, possibly adb method, is root needed?

Tags: browser, android, tabs, session, adb

I've tried every solution recommended. My smartphone is not rooted, it is an LG L355DL, LG K31 Rebel, Android version 10. I got many tabs on my browsers that I need to transfer & review. When I try to transfer each tab one by one using my phone, old social media sessions, Facebook links, etc, I open the tab, but they reset their URL to facebook.com/login, so I often lose where I was at completely when I try to click on them to share/transfer them to my PC or anywhere.

In other words I have to open the tab again, refresh the URL, but in the process the URL changes & sometimes resets itself to the domain, common thing that happens when you're not re-logged into social media, etc. So I need a walk-through to access the session/tab files via adb method, or something.

I do not have root access to my phone. I tried to do adb pull /data/data/com.styxbrowser.browser/app_chrome/Default/* etc. I connected my PC to my phone via USB, but it doesn't work. Also this forum post may help. Here are my terminal results/attempts: [www.rentry.co/cyube](http://www.rentry.co/cyube).

Lastly, there is interestingly another very different approach to accessing these files, it worked for my Android Kiwi browser. I connected my android to my PC via USB, opened my kiwibrowser on my Android, turned on adb on my phone, then I went to chrome://inspect/#devices in my browser on my PC. I could see all tabs & could back them all up. it works like a charm. However, it doesn't work with Styx or Duckduckgo. Not sure why.

-Thanks!

Comment: Accessing app data in `/data/data/` requires root permissions and rooting your phone will erase al user data.

Comment: Thanks, there are some known workarounds for accessing data without root. Also there is the chrome://inspect/#devices approach too. I just dont know enough about these subjects.

Comment: chrome://inspect/#devices is called Chrome remote debugging. It is only available in Chrome and other apps that use WebView and are debuggable (all apps from Play Store are not debuggable) or explicitly enable remote debugging.

Comment: This question has already been posted (cross post) where it belongs: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/252093/2241 -> can be closed here

Comment: Thanks for moving it to android forum, if that is what is appropriate. I am very new to these forums, so please excuse me, I simply tried to post in multiple forums.

Does PC firefox have a remote debugging feature? for firefox mobile? Maybe styx & duckduckgo are firefox based?  Kiwi browser is google based & worked with chrome remote debugging.

Comment: Unlikely, most browsers are Chromium based.